# How to make object invalid in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to make ruby object invalid in Rails but it's not working. Please see below code:

```
irb> user = User.first
irb> user.valid? # returns true
irb> user.errors[:base] << 'Making it Invalid'
irb> user.valid? # still returns true
```

So how is `user` object still returning as valid even when I added errors to the base. So how can I make my user object invalid in `irb` ?

Answer (score 2):

> So how is user object still returning as valid even when I added errors to the base?

This is what `valid?` does under the hood ([docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.6/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L336)).

```
# Runs all the specified validations and returns +true+ if no errors were
# added otherwise +false+.
def valid?(context = nil)
  current_context, self.validation_context = validation_context, context
  errors.clear
  run_validations!
ensure
  self.validation_context = current_context
end
```

As you can see `errors.clear` is called right before the validations are triggered, that's why it returns `true`

> So how can I make my user object invalid in irb?

The only way I could make it invalid is by forcing an attribute, which has validations on it, to be invalid.

```
user = User.last
user.valid? # => true
user.email = nil
user.valid? # => false
user.errors.messages # => {:email=>["can't be blank", "is invalid"]}
```

I see from the comment on the other answer that it's not what you need/want but it's just how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think by default the `valid?` function will clear up the `errors` for each call. So you cannot append to it, you can try to make one or more attributes to be invalid instead.

Comment: How to make attributes invalid ?

Comment: Is there any validation on the `User` class ? If yes, you can make the attributes invalid. Ex: `user.name = nil` or something.

Comment: ok gotcha but that won't solve my problem.